# Why is it not possible to use the constructor parameter (not property) directly as variables for a member function?

Tags: kotlin, parameters, properties, member-functions

Following example will describe my misunderstanding the best I think:

```
class myExampleClass (
    myString: String,
    val myInt: Int,
) {

    fun memberFunction() {
        val memberFunctionValA = myString // does not work
        val memberFunctionValB = myInt // does work
    }
}
```

Is there a specific reason? Do we always have to declare parameters as properties to use them inside the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax:

```
class Person(val firstName: String, val lastName: String, var age: Int) { /*...*/ }
```

I found this on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/classes.html
As far as I can understand you missed a val keyword in the first parameter.

```
class myExampleClass (
    val myString: String,        // this might work
    val myInt: Int,
) {

    fun memberFunction() {
        val memberFunctionValA = myString // does not work
        val memberFunctionValB = myInt // does work
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if there is a specific reason why it has to be declared as a property (with the val keyword). Or is it just "this is it how it is"?

Comment: It's just how it is. The developers wanted to differentiate between initializable and non variables in constructors. I haven't used kotlin a lot but maybe it's efficient this way for some purpose.

Comment: ah, ok, please include that in your answer, so I can check it off

Comment: "for declaring properties and initializing them from the primary constructor, Kotlin has a concise syntax:" It was already there. I found it on the kotlin documentation. Did you mean something else?